# Getting order of magnitude in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to obtain the order of magnitude of a number in Mathematica? E.g. 200 would have an order of magnitude of 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`RealExponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RealExponent.html?q=RealExponent&lang=en). Strictly speaking, though, this is just as easily accomplished by `Floor@Log[10, Abs[num]]`.

Comment: IntegerExponent doesn't give the order of magnitude. Try `IntegerExponent[2300]`.

Comment: @wrongusername On the page guide/Syntax in the documentation center, you'll  find a few more of these useful abbreviations, look under the 'Short forms' header. At first they tend to be confusing, but you'll discover they come in handy once you start doing  _functional programming_ stuff (see guide/FunctionalProgramming).

Answer (score 4):

Start with

```
Log[10., 200]

2.30103
```

and use Round, Floor, Ceiling (or not) to taste.

Answer (score 2):

Use [IntegerLength](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntegerLength.html) to get the number of digits of an integer.

```
In[3]:= n=200;

In[4]:= IntegerLength[n] - 1

Out[4]= 2
```

Alternatively, if the number can be a non-integer, you could just use the log function

```
In[6]:= Floor[Log10[n]]

Out[6]= 2
```

Comment: nit, `n` can be negative which means `Log10` will return a complex number.